# How to get averages of values from multiple data sets written to one output file

Tags: r, loops, astronomy

so I've used R for a few years but I find thinking around coding issues pretty hard still so if any explanations can assume as little as possible I'd really appreciate it!

Basically, I have lots of data files that correspond to different dates. I would like to write some sort of loop where I can have each day's data file be read in, analysis taken place (e.g. the mean of one of the columns) and the output go to a separate file labelled by the date/name of the file (The date isn't currently part of the data file so I haven't figured out how to have that in the code yet)

To complicate things I need to pull out subsets from the data file to analyze separately. I've figured out how to do this and get the separate means already I just don't know how to incorporate the loop.

```
#separating LINK (SL) satellites from entire list
SL<- data[grepl("^LINK", data$name), ]
#separating non-SL sat. from entire list
nonSL<- data[!grepl("^LINK", data$name), ]


analyse<- function(filenames){
  #mean mag. for satellites in data frame
  meansat<- print(mean(data[,2]))
  #mean mag. for LINK sat. in data frame
  meanSLsat<- print(mean(SL[,2]))
  #mean mag. non-SL sat. in data frame
  meannonSLsat<- print(mean(nonSL[,2]))
  means<-c(meansat, meanSLsat, meannonSLsat)
}

#looping in data files
filenames<- list.files(path = "Data")
for (f in filenames) {
  print(f)
  allmeans<-analyse(f)
}

write.table(allmeans, file = "outputloop.txt", col.names = "Mean Magnitude", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

This is what I have so far, but it's not working and I don't understand why. There are feeble attempts for a loop but I have no idea where/the order for putting in a loop when I need to then separate out the subclasses, so any help would be really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for (f in filenames) {
  allmeans <-analyse(f)
  file_out <- paste(f, "_output.txt", sep='') # This is for creating different filenames for each file analyzed
  write.table(allmeans, file = file_out , col.names = "Mean Magnitude", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That alteration just created multiple out files but they still only had the values from the last analysed data file. So I had two files that started with the input name and then had output.txt on the end.

Comment: you can just take care of reading one file and analyze that file in your analyse function with one filename as argument. Then the loop will serve your purpose, I think

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, would you mind explaining in a little more detail please?

Comment: in your analyse function you are not reading any file. I meant you include file reading code inside your analyse function: analyse<- function(filename){data<-read.csv(filename) ... }